# Firebase上のログイン情報の管理はどうすればいいですか？

Tags: swift, ios, firebase

お世話になっております。
クライアントから受注したiOSのアプリにFirebaseを使ってログイン機能を持たせた場合、Firebase上にユーザーの情報が蓄積されていくのでしょうか？その場合、この情報の管理は誰がするのが一般的なのでしょうか？
クライアントに専門的な知識がない場合、開発者が管理することになるのではと思うのですが、その場合、どのような形でクライアントと契約を結べばよいのでしょうか？
firebaseのアカウントは、クライアントか開発者のどちらのものにすればよいですか？

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebaseのログイン機能を使うと、WEB上で閲覧できるFirebaseコンソールのAuthenticationのところに
ログインしたユーザーが保管されていきます。
そこで出る情報（メールアドレス等）で事足りる場合は、それ上での管理で問題ないと思いますが
ユーザー名や他の情報も管理したい場合だと、FireStoreや別DBなどで管理するのがいいと思います。

Firebasenoアカウントをどちらで管理するかどうかは、契約や、請求がどちらでするかなどもあるので
当事者で決めて頂くしかないかと…

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！助かります！アカウントの管理は、どちらかがするということなのですね。単にログインできれば良いだけという場合は、アカウントの所有者だけを決めて、コンソールはほったらかしでもいいという認識でいいでしょうか？

Comment: ↑（別の質問として立てた方がいいかもしれませんが）

Comment: クライアントに専門的な知識がないとのことなので、基本的には開発者側が管理するのが無難かなと。
本当にログイン機能のみ使えれば良いのであれば特に放置でも問題ないとは思いますが、コンソールから、どの程度の情報が保持されてるのか確認して頂いたほうが良いかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます！助かります！